# Symfony Form Collection of Custom Types

Tags: php, symfony-forms, symfony4

I got current an issue that I found no real solution so far.
Here is what I need:

I have an array field in my doctrine model that should store the following informations:

```
[
    [
        'name'=>'John Doe',
        'email'=>'john@doe.com',
    ],
    [
        'name'=>'Jake Doe',
        'email'=>'jake@doe.com',
    ],
]
```

I added the following Type to my code:

```
    <?php
    declare(strict_types=1);

    namespace App\Form\Component;

    use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\BuilderAwareInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;


    /**
     * Class EmailType
     * @package MjrOne\Form\Component
     */
    class EmailType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder->add(
                'name',
                TextType::class,
                [
                    'required'=>true,
                ]
            )->add(
                'email',
                TextType::class,
                [
                    'required'=>true,
                ]
            );
        }
    }
```

I added the following build form to my code:

```
        ->add(
            'toReceiver',
            CollectionType::class,
            [
                'entry_type'=>EmailType::class,
                'allow_add'=>true,
                'allow_delete'=>true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'prototype' => true,
                'entry_options'=>[
                    'required'=>true,
                ]
            ]
        )
```

But I only receive an "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion")." Error message.
What did I miss?
The Structure inside the form works (I added it manually to the database and checked it when loading the entity). The Entity works as expected (including the data structure).
But symphony does render it as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the error you're reporting has only to do with your rendering strategy, and nothing to do with the forms you've defined above - they look sound.

```
<ul data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.toReceiver.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
    {% for receiver in form.toReceiver %}
        {{ form_widget(receiver) }}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This treats each collection item as it's own widget, and puts the prototype for rendering new ones in an attribute of the container. (You can use JS to handle create/delete operations, as detailed in [this Form Collections guide on the official Symfony docs!](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype))

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved it now differently by adding an additional entity. It didn't work as expected with array form fields and subforms. So I had to switch to the entity version, which works quite well. I am also reusing the email part in the other entries that I have emails in and so I can store all emails in an central place

Comment: That's great, @ChrisWest! It'd be interesting to see your alternate approach in a separate answer for any future readers who come to this page with a similar problem